# TypeScript: Infer argument type based on return type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define a function `wrap` such that this works?:

```js
function wrap<Self>(
  creator: (self: Self) => Self
) {}

wrap(self => ({
  val: 2,

  func(): number {
    return self.val;
  }
}));
```

As it is TypeScript complains at `return self.val;` with the error:

> Property 'val' does not exist on type '{}'.

I'm hoping `wrap` can be defined in such a way that the type of `self` is inferred to be the same type as the return value of the function.

Comment: Can't see the error here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20wrap%3CSelf%3E(%0D%0A%20%20creator%3A%20(self%3A%20Self)%20%3D%3E%20Self%0D%0A)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Awrap(self%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20val%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20func()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20self.val%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))%3B

Comment: Looks like this works in TypeScript 3.4.3 but broke in 3.4.4... Playground must be running a slightly older version...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Self` is just a generic. The compiler has no way of knowing that objects represented by `Self` have a `val` attribute (or even any properties at all; for all it knows, they're just of type `{}`).

To let it know what can be expected of `Self`:

```
interface HasVal {
    val: any;
}

function wrap<Self extends HasVal>(
    creator: (self: Self) => Self
) {}

wrap(self => ({
    val: 2,

    func(): number {
        return self.val;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Yeah that's intentional. I want to use this for a general purpose library where `Self` could be anything, so I don't want to apply a constraint on it. I just want the type of the `self` argument to be inferred as the same type as the returned object, whatever that may be.